# Android development- Make button open new screen

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is probably really simple but I've followed several different instructions and cant seem to get it to work. Basically all I want to do is create a button in an xml layout under(main_activity) reference it in java (MainActivity), then set up that button to open its own new xml file. As of now when I click on the button (on my phone not the emulator) is crashes. This is what I have so far. Thanks for looking at it.

xml screen one

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Application"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvFirst"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java screen1

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonOne.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
}
}
```

xml screen2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvButtonOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is te button one screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java screen2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    findViewById(R.layout.buttonone);
}

}
```

Comment: It will be helpful to post error message from logcat

Answer (score 1):

@javac and @A-C are both right, you need to call `setContentView`, however also make sure that you have declared the new activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
android:name="NAME"
android:label="@string/string_name"/>
```

Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#AddToManifest) to see what the Android docs have to say.

To help you gain a broader understanding, the workflow of what you're trying to do will be like this:

1. Start activity 1
2. (in `onCreate()`) `onClickListener` gets set for button
3. button gets pressed
4. `onClickListener` runs, calling `startActivity()`
5. In `startActivity()`, the system ensures that you've declared the activity in AndroidManifest.xml, and if you have, it starts the activity.
6. (in `onCreate()`) call `setContentView()`, which tells the new activity how to lay itself out, and also makes calls to `findViewById()` work as you expect them to.
7. Call `findViewById()` to get a reference to the view you want to be able to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because you are calling `findViewById(R.layout.buttonone);` without giving anything for your new Activity to work with - it can't find R.layout.buttonone because

- You have not set this Activity's layout
- You are trying to find a layout file, which is not a view, but an xml that defines how Views are arranged; a layout of View Objects.

What this means is that you need to replace `findViewById(R.layout.buttonone);` with `setContentView (R.layout.buttonone);`

From there you can use `findViewById()` to get the **components** defined in the xml file, such as `tvButtonOne`. Make sure that each component you want to access has its own id, otherwise you crash your app again.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you have two screens (2 activities) and when the button is clicked it launches screen2. Well on the screen2 class, you do not have a view defined.

Use this line to reference the xml file

```
setContentView(xmlfilenamehere);
```

And here is some info on starting a second activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html